# Increment row or column of a datagridview in c # and sql

Tags: c#

Good morning, I am trying to autoincrement column 0 "ITEM" of my datagridview, when I click on the button to add photo attachment.

[image]

but I can not find the function to increase the column "ITEM" in this case it would be "004", I attach the code to show contacts this through my data_layer

```js
public DataTable Contactos_ClieProvs(String basesita, String codClie)
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            try
            {
                SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection(conexion.CargarBase(basesita));
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("execute CONTACTOS @tipo=13,@IdClieProv='" + codClie + "'", cnn);
                //cmd.CommandTimeout = 0;
                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                try
                {
                    if (cnn.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                    {
                        cnn.Open();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        cnn.Close();
                        cnn.Open();
                    }
                    da.Fill(dt);
                }
                catch (SqlException ex) { throw ex; }
                finally
                {
                    cnn.Close();
                }
            }
            catch (SqlException ex1) { throw ex1; }
            return dt;
        }
```

now I show it as follows in the form.

```
    private void txtcod_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (txtcod.Text == "")
        {



        }
        else {
            var dt = negCli.DatosContacto(MODULOS.Globales.Base, txtcod.Text);
            bs.DataSource = dt;
            bs.AddingNew += bs_AddingNew;
            dt.RowDeleting += dt_RowDeleting;
            this.dgvcontactos.DataSource = bs;

           // this.dgvcontactos.DataSource = negCli.DatosContacto(MODULOS.Globales.Base, txtcod.Text);
        
        }
    }
```

**this is the code of the button add new row.**

```
    private void AGREGAR_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        bs.AddNew();
       
       // this.dgvcontactos.EditMode = DataGridViewEditMode.EditOnEnter;
        this.AGREGAR.Enabled = false;
        
    }
```

but so far I can't autoincrement the ITEM column by c #, through sql server I have a procedure that returns the next item number, but in this case I'm trying to do it by vb c # forms, some idea for this case.

**I found 1 solution with the following code**

```
this.dgvcontactos.Rows [e.RowIndex] .Cells [0] .Value = (e.RowIndex + 1) .ToString ();
```

but it shows me as follows and I'm looking forward to it showing this way "004" ...

Comment: I see the <sql> tag, but I can't see how this is related to the SQL _language_.

Comment: execute CONTACTOS @tipo=13,@IdClieProv=

Comment: Is that SQL? Which dbms?

Comment: sql expres 2018.8

Comment: Use RowsAdded Event : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.rowsadded?force_isolation=true&view=net-5.0

Comment: Provided DGV column `ITEM` is mapped to a Sql table PK it should be controlled by the server side only.  It's a server job to assign an autogenerated PK.

Comment: I understand your point of view, the Item field should be a self-incrementing field since the database would be the most practical and simple thing, in this case they posed me this task where the ITEM field is of type char (3) where y is not self-incrementing, that's why I look for one function to be incremented in the datagridview

Comment: This question has nothing to do with VB.NET or SQL Server. Don't spam tags to get more people to see your question. Tags are for our sake, so we know whether a question is relevant to us. Tricking people into reading your question is not the way to make friends.